# Oversampling multiclass data failing using ADASYN algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, imblearn

I have a very basic script below to demo the problem:

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import ADASYN
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


data = pd.read_csv('glass.csv')
classes = data.values[:, -1]
data = data.iloc[:, :-1]

adasyn = ADASYN(sampling_strategy='not majority', random_state=8, n_neighbors=3)

new_data, new_classes = adasyn.fit_resample(data, classes)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(new_data, new_classes, test_size = 0.20)

rfc = RandomForestClassifier()
rfc.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Score: {}".format(rfc.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

[Note, `glass.csv` comes from this link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/glass.csv)

The intention would be to balance the below class imbalances:

```
(214, 10)
Class=1, Count=70, Percentage=32.710%
Class=2, Count=76, Percentage=35.514%
Class=3, Count=17, Percentage=7.944%
Class=5, Count=13, Percentage=6.075%
Class=6, Count=9, Percentage=4.206%
Class=7, Count=29, Percentage=13.551%
```

To have equal (or near equal) samples. However, running the code above produces:

`ValueError: No samples will be generated with the provided ratio settings.`

Changing `ADASYN`'s `sampling_strategy` to `minority` successfully oversamples the `minority` class, `6`, and brings it to `74` samples, but still leaves the remaining classes imbalanced. Thus, I am looking for a way to completely oversample **all minority classes** using ADASYN.

[ADASYN documentation states:](https://imbalanced-learn.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.ADASYN.html#imblearn.over_sampling.ADASYN)
`'not majority': resample all classes but the majority class;`

But that clearly is not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, what I did was resampled all but the two major majority classes, and continued to do so via:

```
adasyn = ADASYN(sampling_strategy='minority', random_state=8, n_neighbors=3)

new_data = data
new_classes = classes

for i in range(len(classes)-2):
    new_data, new_classes = adasyn.fit_resample(data, classes)
```